# Spring mvc : org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsp, spring-jdbc

Please do not mark it as duplicate as i was not able to find the solution anywhere.

I am new to spring mvc and trying to write a program where i have to store the values of pojo class in database but was struck with the following exception.
Please help with the error.

nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection

Index.jsp from where i enter values for my pojo class whose values has to be stored in the database.

```
  <%@page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
   pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

   <html>
     <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" >
      <title>Insert title here</title>
    </head>

    <body>
      <form  id="myform" method="post" action="spkr">
         <label>First Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="fname" >
         <label">Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="lname" >
         <label>DOB</label>
            <input type="text" name="dob"/ >
         <label >Gender</label>                     
            <input type="radio" name="optionradio" id="optionsRadios1" 
             value="Male" checked="">Male
           <input type="radio" name="optionradio" id="optionsRadios2" 
            value="Female">Female

         <label >Emailid</label>
            <input type="text" name="mail" placeholder="">

         <label>Achivements</label>
            <input type="text" name="ach" placeholder="organization">

         <label> Skills</label>
             <input type="text" name="skill" placeholder="">

         <label>Pincode</label>
             <input type="text" name="pcode"/>

         <label>Organization</label>    
             <input type="text" name="organization" 
              placeholder="organization">

             <input type="submit">Submit</input>

       </form>
   </body>
 </html>
```

POJO CLASS with getters and setters for the variables for

```
 Spkr.java

 package com.spkr.DO;
 import javax.persistence.Entity;
 import javax.persistence.Id;

 @Entity
 public class Spkr {
@Id
private String fname;
private String lname;
private String gen;
private String mail;
private String ach;
private String skill;
private String org;

public Spkr(){

}

public Spkr( String fname, String lname, String gen, String mail, String ach, String skill, String org) {
    super();

    this.fname = fname;
    this.lname = lname;
    this.gen = gen;
    this.mail = mail;
    this.ach = ach;
    this.skill = skill;
    this.org = org;
}


public String getFname() {
    return fname;
}
public void setFname(String fname) {
    this.fname = fname;
}
public String getLname() {
    return lname;
}
public void setLname(String lname) {
    this.lname = lname;
}
public String getGen() {
    return gen;
}
public void setGen(String gen) {
    this.gen = gen;
}
public String getMail() {
    return mail;
}
public void setMail(String mail) {
    this.mail = mail;
}
public String getAch() {
    return ach;
}
public void setAch(String ach) {
    this.ach = ach;
}
public String getSkill() {
    return skill;
}
public void setSkill(String skill) {
    this.skill = skill;
}
public String getOrg() {
    return org;
}
public void setOrg(String org) {
    this.org = org;
}
}
```

SpeakerAddService.java(Service Interface)

```
 package com.spkr.service;
 import com.spkr.DO.Spkr;
 public interface SpeakerAddService {
 public void add(Spkr s);
 }
```

SpeakerAddServiceImpl.java

```
package com.spkr.service;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import com.spkr.DO.Spkr;
import com.spkr.dao.SpeakerDao;

public class SpeakerAddServiceImpl implements SpeakerAddService{

@Autowired
SpeakerDao sas;

public SpeakerAddServiceImpl() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

    public void add(Spkr s) {


    //System.out.println(fname +" "+skill);
    System.out.println("Hi service");
    System.out.println(s.getMail()+" "+s.getLname()+" "+s.getGen()+" 
  "+s.getAch());
    System.out.println(s.getFname()+" "+s.getSkill());
    sas.addSpeaker(s);
}}
```

SpeakerDao.java(Interface)

```
package com.spkr.dao;
 import com.spkr.DO.Spkr;
 public interface SpeakerDao {
 public void addSpeaker(Spkr s);
  }
```

SpeakerDaoImpl,java

```
 package com.spkr.dao;

  import org.hibernate.Session;
  import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
  import org.hibernate.Transaction;
  import org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration;
  import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

  import com.spkr.DO.Spkr;

  public class SpeakerDaoImpl implements SpeakerDao{

   @Autowired()
   public SpeakerDaoImpl(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    this.sessionfactory = sessionFactory;
    }
  private SessionFactory sessionfactory;
   public void addSpeaker(Spkr s) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("Hi database");
    System.out.println(s.getAch()+" "+s.getFname()+" "+s.getGen()+" 
   "+s.getLname()+" "+s.getMail()+" "+s.getOrg()+" "+s.getSkill());
    /*Session session = sessionfactory.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    session.save(s);*/
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    Session session = sessionfactory.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();

    session.save(s);
    session.getTransaction().commit();

    System.out.println("one record friend--");
}

 }
```

spkr-servlet.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <beans:beans xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

  <mvc:annotation-driven />
  <context:annotation-config/>

  <context:component-scan base-package="com.spkr.controller">
  </context:component-scan>

 <beans:bean 

 class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
   <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"></beans:property>
  <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></beans:property>
  </beans:bean>

  <beans:bean id="speakerAddService" 
  class="com.spkr.service.SpeakerAddServiceImpl"/>     
  <beans:bean id="s" class="com.spkr.dao.SpeakerDaoImpl"/>   

 <beans:bean id="sessionFactory" 
class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">

<beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />





          <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
                 <beans:props>
                       <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</beans:prop>
                       <beans:prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</beans:prop>
                       <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</beans:prop>
                 </beans:props>
          </beans:property>

          <beans:property name="annotatedClasses">
        <beans:list>
              <beans:value>com.spkr.DO.Spkr</beans:value> <!-- Entity classes-->

        </beans:list>
        </beans:property>
   </beans:bean>

 <beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" 
  destroy-method="close">
          <beans:property name="driverClassName" 
  value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
          <beans:property name="url" 
  value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/student" />
          <beans:property name="username" value="root" />
          <beans:property name="password" value="root" />
</beans:bean>

</beans:beans>
```

web.xml

```
 <!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
"-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

 <web-app>

 <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

 <servlet>
 <servlet-name>spkr</servlet-name>
 <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet- 
 class>
 <init-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spkr-servlet.xml</param-value>
</init-param>
 <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>

 <servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>spkr</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>

 </web-app>
```

Error Description

```
 nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to 
 acquire JDBC Connection

 Root cause
 org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create 
 PoolableConnectionFactory (initializeConnection: connection closed)  

 Root cause
 java.sql.SQLException: initializeConnection: connection closed
```

Comment: maybe unrelated but what is this: `@Autowired()
   public SpeakerDaoImpl(SessionFactory sessionFactory)`? I think you mean to use @Repository on the class, like `@Repository public class SpeakerDaoImpl implements SpeakerDao`

Comment: @Autowired is used to create objects.it creates automatically when we use this annotation.but SpeakerDao is an interface so,what i did was in spkr-servlet.xml file observe this line of code.   <beans:bean id="s" class="com.spkr.dao.SpeakerDaoImpl"/>   Which means the springmvc checks any autowired annotations and if present creates an object of SpeakerDaoImpl which is a class that implements SpeakerDao interface

Comment: @JackFlamp please provide your view to solve this program.Thank you in advance :-)

Comment: ok I hadn't seen autowired used on constructors before. I usually use on instance fields.. anyhow..

Comment: So you have probably tried using `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost` and username and password are correct? someone had a problem with a visurprogram called Avast and had to shut that down. Does the autowiring of SpeakerDao work properly?

Comment: try annotating your SpeakerDaoImpl with `@Repository` and remove the `()` after `@autowired` on the constructor.